# Retrieve data from firebase database to class in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get data from my users from my database. Me need to display all data in tableView on current authorized user.

Now i have this struct in firebase:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "fZjVIhQrqvcQYIa0CjfmDNnaUao2" : {
      "email" : "email@email.email",
      "historyBooking" : {
        "-L5FGrgRULvn_E4GV9ht" : {
          "bookingDate" : "13.02.2018",
          "bookingTime" : "C 02:00 до 3:00 (итого 1 час.)",
          "email" : "",
          "name" : "",
          "phonenumber" : "",
          "studioHallAddress" : "AddressOne",
          "studioHallName" : "HallOne",
          "surename" : "",
          "totalSum" : "1500 руб."
        },
        "-L5FO_GQSLixyRBtjZVt" : {
          "bookingDate" : "14.02.2018",
          "bookingTime" : "C 11:00 до 12:00 (итого 1 час.)",
          "email" : "",
          "name" : "",
          "phonenumber" : "",
          "studioHallAddress" : "AddressTwo",
          "studioHallName" : "HallTwo",
          "surename" : "",
          "totalSum" : "1900 руб."
        }
      },
      "uid" : "fZjVIhQrqvcQYIa0CjfmDNnaUao2",
      "username" : "admin"
    }
  }
}
```

And i have this code:

```
class HistoryBookingViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var historyBooking: [BookingHall] = []

    var userHistoryRef: DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        userHistoryRef = Database.database().reference()

        loadHistoryBooking()

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return historyBooking.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "historyCell", for: indexPath) as! HistoryBookingTableCell

//        cell.studioHallName.text = historyBooking[indexPath.row].studioHallName

        return cell

    }

    func loadHistoryBooking() {

        if let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {

            userHistoryRef.child("users").child(userID).child("historyBooking").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary

                print("value - \(value)")

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            })
        }
    }
}
```

In console i see all data, but how i can apply all data from **firebase** to my **class**?

My class is here:

```
class BookingHall {

    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var studioHallName: String = ""
    var studioHallAddress: String = ""
    var bookingDate: String = ""
    var bookingTime: String = ""
    var totalSum: String = ""
    var name: String = ""
    var surename: String = ""
    var email: String = ""
    var phonenumber: String = ""

    init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

        ref = snapshot.ref

        let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary

    }
}
```

I know I'm missing code in my **class** and in the `loadHistoryBooking()` function, please tell me what to add in my **function** and in my **class**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class you can create custom init method like this

// Note: Some of values are missing here

```
class Model {
    let bookingDate: String
    let bookingTime: String
    let email: String
    let name: String
    let phonenumber: String
    let studioHallAddress: String
    let studioHallName: String
    let surename: String
    let totalSum: String

    init(bookingDate: String, bookingTime: String, email: String, name: String, phonenumber: String, studioHallAddress: String, studioHallName: String, surename: String, totalSum: String) {
        self.bookingDate = bookingDate
        self.bookingTime = bookingTime
        self.email = email
        self.name = name
        self.phonenumber = phonenumber
        self.studioHallAddress = studioHallAddress
        self.studioHallName = studioHallName
        self.surename = surename
        self.totalSum = totalSum
    }
}
```

and you can create object with given details and add that to your global array and you can show to tableview

Comment: how to handle getting data from firebase in ViewController in my `func loadHistoryBooking()`?

Comment: @Dima I suggest you to use https://github.com/alickbass/CodableFirebase for swift4. and for normal case you can loop to children and create object manually and append to global array.

Comment: It's i readed, but i don't understand how get to my elements from my struct in firebase.

Comment: @Dima Download demo from here https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2 you will get understanding

Comment: @Dima If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).